# Injectives envelopes (hulls) in Grothendieck categories: proof from the Freyd's book

Tags: category-theory, proof-explanation, homological-algebra, abelian-categories

Everything is taken from Freyd's book *Abelian categories*.

By a *Grothendieck category* Freyd means a bicomplete well-powered abelian category such that, for $C,(B_i)_{i \in I}$ being subobject of a fixed object with $(B_i)_{i \in I}$ being a chain we have
$$C\cap\left(\bigcup_{i \in I} B_i\right) = \bigcup_{i \in I} (C\cap B_i).$$

In an abelian category, an *extension* of an object $A$ is simply a monomorphism $A\to B$. An injective $u\colon A\to B$ is *essential* if, for any nonzero $v\colon B'\to B$ the intersection of $u$ and $v$, considered as subobjects of $B$, is nonzero.

Let $\mathsf{A}$ be a Grothendieck category with a generator $G$. Then $\mathsf{Hom_A}(G,-)$ is a functor into the category of $R$-modules where $R = \mathsf{End_A}(G)$ with the $R$-module structure on $\mathsf{Hom_A}(G,A)$ being defined by composition: $rf = f\circ r$.

> *Lemma.* If $u\colon A\to E$ is a an essential extension in $\mathsf{A}$, then $\mathsf{Hom_A}(G,u)\colon \mathsf{Hom_A}(G,A)\to\mathsf{Hom_A}(G,E)$ is an essential extension in $R\text{-}\mathsf{Mod}$.

Freyd provides the following proof:

[image]

It is not clear to me $P \neq 0$. Indeed, the pullback of $\mathrm{im}(x)$ along $u$ is nonzero as it is their intersection, but here $x$ is not necessary a monomorphism. Moreover, for there to exist $G\to P$ such that $G \to P \to G \xrightarrow{x} E \neq 0$ (as $G$ is a generator), we must have $P \to G \xrightarrow{x} E \neq 0$. Again, for this follow we need either $x$ to be a monomorphism and $P\to G \neq 0$ or to $u$ to be an epimorphism, from which it would follows that it is an isomorphism, which I find unlikely.

Is this proof correct? If yes, what am I missing? If not, can it be salvaged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Factor $x$ by the image as you suggest:

$$x: G \stackrel{\pi}\twoheadrightarrow \mathrm{Im}\,x \hookrightarrow E. $$

Now one can use the fact that "pullback squares can be pasted together", in other words, the pullback square you have decomposes as pair of pullback squares:

\begin{array}
\\
G & \stackrel{\pi}\twoheadrightarrow  & \mathrm{Im}\,x  & \hookrightarrow &  E\\
\uparrow &   & \uparrow & &\uparrow \\
P & \stackrel{\pi'}\twoheadrightarrow  & P_{im}  & \hookrightarrow &  A\\
 \end{array}

Here $P_{im}$ is nonzero by $A \rightarrow E$ being essential ($\mathrm{Im}\,x$ is nonzero since so is $x$). The map $\pi'$ is an epimorphism since so is $\pi,$ and epimorphisms are preserved by pullbacks in abelian categories. Thus, $P$ admits an epimorphism onto a nonzero object, and it follows that it is itself nonzero.

Comment: Nice! In fact, this also answers my second question. Indeed, if $P\to G \to E$ is zero, then $P\to P_{im}\to A\to E$ is zero, but $P\to P_{im}$ and $A\to E$ are an epimorphism and a monomorphism, so $P_{im}\to A$ is zero, which is not true (the intersection of $A\to E$ and $\mathrm{im}(x)\to E$ is $P_{im}\to A \to E = P_{im}\to\mathrm{im}(x)\to E$). Thanks a lot!